# Matriz Booleana Aleatória em C++

Tags: c++, matriz, random, booleano

boa tarde.

Preciso desenvolver uma matriz booleana (quase um grafo) aleatória em C++, mas confesso que usava muito python, então estou com dificuldades em começar.

Mas o foco da pergunta é, quando estão programando algo em C++, e precisam criar uma matriz, vocês usam alguma biblioteca ou desenvolvem o código conforme necessidade?

Existe alguma biblioteca boa para trabalhar com vetores?

Comment: Olá! Sua pergunta está muito genérica, e eu tomei liberdade de responder como compreendi pois o tema me interessa. Procure definir melhor suas intenções e mostrar trechos relevantes do código que está escrevendo. Além disso, `Existe alguma biblioteca boa para trabalhar com vetores?` é tão aberto que desanima responder. Talvez algum fórum sobre o assunto seja melhor que o Stack Overflow (no site americano, perguntas assim costumam ser fechadas).

Comment: Eu dei um downvote que pretendo reverter se você melhorar a questão, veja isso como uma crítica construtiva =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta está bem genérica e depois abre em uma questão de opinião pessoal.

Quanto a gerar uma matriz booleana aleatória:

```
using namespace std;
int const LARGURA = 10;
int const ALTURA  =  5;

mt19937 gen(666); // gera números aleatórios mersenne twister
uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 1); //distribuição linear entre 0 e 1

vector<vector<int>> M;
M.resize(ALTURA);
for(auto & linha : M)
{ 
    linha.resize(LARGURA);
    for(auto & valor: linha)
    {
        valor = dis(gen); //sorteia 
    }
}
```

gera o resultado:

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Verifique o exemplo acima em: https://ideone.com/HwwzI1

Quanto a

> quando estão programando algo em C++, e precisam criar uma matriz, vocês usam alguma biblioteca ou desenvolvem o código conforme necessidade?

Depende do projeto. O C++ não possui Matrizes no sentido matemático, com operações aritméticas definidas, para este tipo de operação é melhor usar uma biblioteca externa.

No exemplo acima eu representei uma Matriz como um vetor de vetores.

> Existe alguma biblioteca boa para trabalhar com vetores?

Sim. Matrizes e vetores tem muitas aplicações e aconselho buscar uma biblioteca para a área de interesse. Experimente com algumas e tente familiarizar-se com a tipagem forte do C++, que torna o código bem mais verboso que Python. Bons estudos e boa sorte =)